# Fortify vs DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, fortify

Running HP Fortify against a C#/.NET project. The very act of feeding a JSON document from a Web source to .NET's `DataContractJsonSerializer` triggers a "JSON Injection" issue in Fortify.

The following snippet would cause it:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string s = wc.DownloadString(SomeURL);
using (MemoryStream mst = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)))
    return new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SomeType)).ReadObject(mst) as SomeType;
```

What's Fortify's problem with deserializing JSON like that? The class has been in .NET for a while now.

EDIT: quoting the description:

> 1. Data enters a program from an untrusted source.
>
> In this case the data enters at DownloadString() in SF.cs at line 43.
>
> 2. The data is written to a JSON stream.
>
> In this case the JSON is written by ReadObject()  in SF.cs at line 45.
>
> Applications typically use JSON to store data or send messages. When
>   used to store data, JSON is often treated like cached data and may
>   potentially contain sensitive information. When used to send messages,
>   JSON is often used in conjunction with a RESTful service and can be
>   used to transmit sensitive information such as authentication
>   credentials.
>
> The semantics of JSON documents and messages can be altered if an
>   application constructs JSON from unvalidated input. In a relatively
>   benign case, an attacker may be able to insert extraneous elements
>   that cause an application to throw an exception while parsing a JSON
>   document or request. In a more serious case, such as that involving
>   JSON injection, an attacker may be able to insert extraneous elements
>   that allow for the predictable manipulation of business critical
>   values within a JSON document or request. In some cases, JSON
>   injection can lead to cross-site scripting or dynamic code evaluation.

Okay, to summarize, the risks from a malicious JSON are:

1. Exceptions
2. Manipulation of logic
3. XSS or dynamic evaluation

Number 1 is the desired behavior - if the JSON is grossly malformed, the application throws its hands up and stops. #2 is possible, but how do I validate for that without parsing? #3 is impossible, since the parsing logic is not JavaScript `eval()`.

EDIT2: The other .NET's JSON reader, `JavaScriptSerializer`, causes no errors in Fortify. Weird.

Comment: You can read the description though in the Fortify analyser; the most probable reason IMO is `new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s))` -- no validation applied for string s!

Comment: What kind of validation am I expected to apply to the string? It's a JSON. Parsing *is* the first step towards validating.

Comment: Hi @SevaAlekseyev -As I said in the first comment, it is warning you because of no sanity check of string s (*there is a reason why these are static code analysers*). You can suppress this warning if you think it will not affect your application/code.

Comment: Still don't get it. How do I perform a sanity check on a JSON of a complex object graph before parsing it? I know I can suppress it; that's not the point.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear on what I'm trying to make you understand is actually getting conveyed! You should check the sanity of the value `wc.DownloadString(SomeURL)`. Check if the resultant string is not malformed, etc. for avoiding common vulnerabilities! Hope it helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. **Where's the risk in parsing?** Unless the parser is `window.eval()`, which it's not, there is no risk. If the string is malformed, the parser will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if any dates are being exchanged, the data contact serializer for json tries to process dates as `Date(...)` embedded commands, rather than iso strings

Comment: There aren't. Then again, Fortify is static and doesn't know that. That said, if the way it handles dates was indeed a generic security vulnerability, wouldn't Microsoft have addressed it by now? A cite from Fortify's vendor would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I have to disagree with [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659411/fortify-vs-datacontractjsonserializer?noredirect=1#comment90316583_51659411):

-> Where's the risk in parsing? Unless the parser is window.eval(), which it's not, there is no risk. If the string is malformed, the parser will throw an exception.

The actual complaint here is not of parser directly, but the values being passed to the parser. You are assuming that the data being read / passed is either JSON or not, which would lead to exception if the latter, but, you're missing an important point that there could be dangerous valid JSONs which might affect your program logic, or may lead to other serious vulnerabilities.

If you'd go through the [Fortify's description about JSON Injection](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.dataflow.java.json_injection#C%23%2FVB.NET%2FASP.NET), there is a good point being made which you're not paying attention to:

> The semantics of JSON documents and messages can be altered if an
>   application constructs JSON from unvalidated input. In a relatively
>   benign case, an attacker may be able to insert extraneous elements
>   that cause an application to throw an exception while parsing a JSON
>   document or request. In a more serious case, such as ones that
>   involves JSON injection, **an attacker may be able to insert extraneous
>   elements that allow for the predictable manipulation of business
>   critical values within a JSON document or request**. In some cases, **JSON
>   injection can lead to cross-site scripting or dynamic code evaluation**.

So, in your current code, `string s = wc.DownloadString(SomeURL);` is a potential cause of problem. You should check for the sanity of this string s, before streaming it into memory. As mentioned in the paragraph above, in serious cases extraneous elements can be inserted which can affect the business logic. Obviously, this is what a static code analyser could do it for you. ***It's you who knows what data would be passed here, but Fortify doesn't / can't know that.*** After all, Fortify is a static code analyer!

Hence, if you want Fortify to not complain any further, please put a sanity check on the string like testing for cross-site scripting attack based on JSON data, etc. If you're sure that your string is going to be clean always, then you can suppress this warning. Also, just as an additional point, I think (at least to me) it is obvious to encounter these problems with the static code analyser tools.

Comment: Other than in memory - how am I supposed to check the sanity? :):):) I have to parse before I can check for application-level consistency - but the very act of parsing is deemed unsafe.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - I'm not sure if I got your point (please correct me if I've misunderstood your point)! If you meant that you can't do anything on the data before parsing, I think there are couple of things like checking for unsafe <script> blocks, etc. to avoid XSS (I'm unsure about nature of your application), some other check to avoid dynamic code evaluation, etc. I think there should be some test before parsing, so that it can't befool the parser in any possible way (IMHO, you should never trust the data completely; your parser wouldn't listen to you but the data)!

Comment: Dynamic code evaluation **during parsing**? There's no such thing in `DataContractJsonSerializer`. As for the <script> blocks, they only become a danger if I pass the contents of the JSON on to HTML. For the record, this is not even a Web application, it's a command line one. it doesn't emit HTML.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - But that is not known to Fortify; it is only known to you. This is the reason it just assumes that the parsing result could be danger, since you didn't check for the sanity of the string s!